# According to GR, gravitational acceleration is illusion. by analogy is the acceleration caused by lorentz force is also an illusion?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, equivalence-principle

Gravity (considred to be a force) causes an acceleration, and the samething goes for lorentz force its causes charged objects to accelerate, So my question is, is lorentz force acceleration, an illusion.

Comment: it's locally an illusion, locally.

Comment: There have been a string of these questions recently.  Gravity is not an "illusion", even in general relativity.  We're not imagining that the planets orbit the sun.  They really are doing it.

Comment: if it's locally an illusion, einstein field equations must become maxwell's equations at some limit.

Comment: If you think that gravitational acceleration is an illusion, I hope that you do *not* test your hypothesis by jumping off a cliff.

Comment: I think the proper question is “Can electromagnetic force be understood as due to the geometry of spacetime in the same way that gravitational force can?” The answer is “No, at least not at this time, although physicists have tried this approach.”

Comment: if that's so, why do we speak about maxwell's equations and Dirac equation in curved spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

Illusions are not a part  of physics terminology.

One can say that "temperature" is an illusion, because it can be shown to arise from the average statistical behavior of many body particles constituting matter. That would be wrong though.

All established physics theoretical models, which have been validated with data and observations keep being valid, merging smoothly to each other in the phase space overlapping regions, similar to the way that thermodynamics emerges from statistical mechanics.

General Relativity(GR), models mathematically space time as limited by the energy existing in nature, and it can give new results compared  to Newtonian gravity for large distances and large gravitational masses. For smaller distances or masses  the formulae fall back mathematically to to Newtonian gravity (and special relativity four vectors for high velocities) ,i.e. flat spaces.

Gravity is not an illusion, it can be modeled with different mathematics for high masses and even for masses as small as the Earth the mathematics of GR is used to give correct  [GPS measurements](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~pogge/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html). That does not mean that Newtonian mechanics does not hold for most cases where the error need not be that small.